# Views Creation Permissions without table Creation Permissions in POSTGRESQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration, sql-grant, data-management

I have a use case where I want to create a user which should have **access on select for public schema and Views Creation On public schema but not table creation** User can create a new view but not table

```
`--by admin user 
CREATE ROLE view_creator;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO view_creator;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO view_creator;
CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test123';

GRANT view_creator TO test;
-- by user test 
create view test_2 as select * from public.users_test -- This should 
work
CREATE TABLE public.users (
id serial4 NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(50) NULL,
age int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);  --- This should not work`
```

Comment: please show us yoour attempts, by the way your text is hard to read

Comment: please always edit your question with new information, code in comments is also bad to read

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will keep them in mind for next time.

Comment: `CREATE: Create objects (including tables) within this schema`  as you give him such rights, as far as i know you can't not select what he can create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that with permissions. If you have the `CREATE` privilege on a schema, you can create any object there.

Your only option is to write an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) that throws an error whenever the user creates something other than a view. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createeventtrigger.html) for the `CREATE EVENT TRIGGER` syntax and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-EVENT-TRIGGER) for information about writing event triggers in PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Do you have any resources on how to create event triggers? I'm not familiar with the process of creating events.

Comment: I have added links to the documentation. But perhaps it would be easier to change your requirements or to solve the underlying problem in a different fashion.